# Clear terminal screen with a two line prompt and keep both lines visible

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh, ansi-escape, terminfo

I have a two line prompt like below.  Is there a command like `clear` that will clear the screen but keep *both* lines of the prompt visible?

```
~/current/directory git-branch*
$ echo 'hello...
```

Comment: Clear keeps multiline prompts...

Comment: Oh, you're right.  I was using C-l and it doesn't have that same behavior.  I thought they were the same.

Answer (score 1):

short: no, there's no such command.

long: you *could* write a script.  Here's a brief introduction to the topic.

The `clear` program clears the whole screen.  Your shell will draw a new prompt (at the top of the newly cleared screen).  But suppose that you wanted to clear parts of the screen *before* your command completes, and returns to the shell.

Most terminals that you would use support the ANSI escape sequence which clears from the current cursor location to the end of the screen, which is the [terminfo capability `ed`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html):

```
   clr_eos                   ed     cd   clear to end of
                                         screen (P*)
```

shown by [`infocmp`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/infocmp.1m.html) as `ed=\E[J`.

You can use it in a script, e.g., using [`tput`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html):

```
tput ed
```

This is one of the areas where "ansi.sys" differs from the ANSI standard (actually [ECMA-48](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm), see *`8.3.29 ERASE IN PAGE`*).  `ansi.sys` clears the entire screen when it receives

```
printf '\033]J'
```

Some people hard-code this into scripts, and assume that "ansi.sys" matches the standard.  See for example *[How do I get color with VT100?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#vt100_color)* in the ncurses FAQ.

Noting a comment about how to test this: likely there is nothing on your screen below the prompt.  So typing `tput ed` may appear to do nothing.  As noted above, it clears *below* the cursor.  If you want to clear above the (2-line) prompt, that's a little more complicated:

- save the cursor position
- move the cursor up two lines
- clear *before* the cursor
- restore the cursor position.

If your prompt happens to be on the first line of the screen, this *could* be detected using the cursor position report.  But that's more complicated to do than the question as phrased would anticipate.  Assume that there's space above:

```
tput sc
tput cuu 2
tput cub 999
printf '\033[1J'
tput rc
```

A regular `printf` rather than `tput` is used here, because there's no predefined terminfo (or termcap) capability defined for that type of erase.

If you wanted to handle the case where the prompt starts in the top line of the terminal, you'd have to find the current line *number* and decide whether to do the clearing above (or not).

Further reading:

- [Re: cursor position in a variable](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2015/msg00866.html)

Comment: Nor `tput ed` or `printf '\033]J'` are working in `konsole`.

Comment: Neither `tput ed` nor `printf '\033]J'` worked in st (suckless terminal).  Both commands simply return. In xterm, `printf '\033]J'` hangs.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to work, since that's **`OSC J`** rather than **`CSI J`**.  xterm handles it as expected.  Starting from that point, the comment regarding konsole and tput needs some clarification (konsole works as expected also...).